# How to cut off a page early

Tags: html, css, image

So im hosting images on my page and the bottom of the images are uneven, so the bottom of the page is a uneven mess

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3XvJ.png

Normally id try to just fit them together in a way thats a perfect square, but the page is supposed to be responsibe so its impossible to predict how big the page is.

Is there a way to cut off a web page after it reaches a certain %

Comment: What makes you think a responsive page can't be laid out well?

Comment: oh no it can, its just hard to know when to cut off the images to make them even when the page can change sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want the content to be shown till only a certain length. The [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property works best for these cases. I would suggest "wrapping" your entire content with a div. For example:

In your html

```
<div class="wrapper-cutter">
    <!-- Your images/content here -->
</div>
```

In your css

```
.wrapper-cutter {
    height: 300px; /*Pick it whatever you want*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Edit:** Here I am assuming you know the length. From recent comments, there's a chance you don't. If you don't then this approach won't work. You will need js to find out the required length.

Comment: this definitely sounds like a solution that would work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have both images in side by side columns. you will need little JS and css for proper responsive behavior in all devices.e.g

.imageBox{min-height:300px;}

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="imageBox">
      <img src="abc.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="imageBox">
      <img src="abc.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.imageBox').children('img').each(function(n, img) {
            var $img = $(img);
            var $imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');
            $img.parent('.imageBox').css({
                'background': 'transparent url(' + $imgUrl + ') top center  no-repeat',
                'background-size': 'cover',
                '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
                '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
                '-o-background-size': 'cover'
            });
            $img.hide();
        });
```